# array empty cell search algorithm

Tags: search-algorithms, arrays

I'm Telecommunication student so I don't have Computer Science background, just in case if my question looks stupid.

Here is my scenario:

1. Consider an empty array named `ARR` with size `N`, we also have an array named `MAP` with size `N` that stores the state of `ARR` cells, `ON` for filled, `OFF` for empty, initially `ARR` is empty so every corresponding cell in `MAP` is set to `OFF`.
2. we keep the next empty cell index in a variable named `NEXT`, initially since `ARR` is empty, `NEXT` is set to 0. `NEXT` always point to the first index `i` in the array `MAP` such that `MAP[i]` is `OFF`, if any exists.
3. a function named `add(element)` always adds element into `ARR` at index `NEXT`, sets corresponding cell in `MAP` to `ON`.
4. a function named `insert(element, index)` adds element into `ARR` at index specified by user, sets corresponding cell in `MAP` to `ON`.
5. a function named `delete(index)` removes element from `ARR` at index specified by user, sets corresponding cell in `MAP` to `OFF`.

My question:
How to update `NEXT` variable so it points to next empty cell index in `ARR`.

I know I can run a search on `MAP` from 0 to N and stop at the first occurrence of `OFF` and store its index as `NEXT`, but from what I read from online sources it has O(N) performance which is not great, I want to know if there are any better algorithms for this job or not, if not, can I design one myself? which books/online doc should I look into?

Thanks.

Comment: Just to be more precise: should `NEXT` always point to the first index $i$ in the array `MAP` such that `MAP[i]` is `OFF`, if any?

Comment: Hi Mehdi, welcome to cs.stackexchange.com. If the running time is not important for you , when you insert new element, with linear time checking you can find the first empty cell of the array.

Comment: @Steven yes, you got it correct, one of my friends suggested that NEXT itself could be an array to hold several indexes, but we weren't sure about the algorithm so I asked it here.

Comment: Or it's sufficient to  set the next to be element that deleted from the array (according to $delete(index)$ procedure). Or when you call the procedure $Add(element)$ you can find the first cell that empty before inserted element or after it. Finally when you call $ insert(element, index)$, if $next=index$ you can act like that explained for procedure $Add(element)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're on a RAM machine with word size $\Theta(\log N$). Keep a [van Emde Boas tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_Emde_Boas_tree) $T$ storing the empty positions (integers from $1$ to $N$).

Whenever you insert an element $i$, delete $i$ from $T$ (in $O(\log \log N$) time) and set `NEXT` to the minimum element in $T$ (in $O(1)$ time).

Whenever you delete an element $i$, insert $i$ to $T$ and set `NEXT` to the minimum between the current values of `NEXT` and $i$.

This requires $O(\log \log N)$ time per operation but would require time $O(N \log \log N)$ to build the tree.
To improve the construction time to $O(N)$ you can start with a tree containing only the index $1$. Then during the first $N-1$ operations do the following: before the $i$-th operation is performed check if `MAP[i+1]=OFF`. If this is the case, then add $i+1$ to $T$. Proceed with the operation normally. This is taking advantage of the fact that, after the $i$-th operation is performed, we must necessarily have `NEXT<=i+1`.

You can't get much better solutions since you essentially need to solve the [predecessor problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predecessor_problem) which admits a lower bound of $\Omega( \frac{\log \log N}{\log \log \log N})$ for a word size of $\Theta(\log N)$.

For a slower but easier to implement solution replace the van Emde Boas tree with an AVL tree. The initial tree can be built in $O(N)$ time (the keys are sorted) and each operation requires $O(\log N)$ time.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I'll try to implement it into code, I just have a question, $O(N \log \log N)$ to build the tree is juts a 1 time operation right? or per every `add`, `insert`, `delete` I should construct the tree?

Comment: The tree is constructed only once, at the same time when `ARR` and `MAP` are created and initialized.